# How to insert a contingency table into a SQL Server database?

Tags: sql-server

I have an contingency table and want to insert it into a SQL Server database:

Contingency table:

```
|      | soccer  | football  | basketball  |
+------+---------+-----------+-------------
|  Max |    x    |           |      x      |
|  Mary|    x    |           |             |
|  Tim |         |           |      x      |
+------+---------+-----------+-------------
```

Should be transformed via T-SQL INSERT to:

```
| name | sports  | 
+------+---------+
|  Max | soccer  |
|  Max | basketball 
| Mary | soccer  |   
| Tim  | basketball   
+------+---------+
```

Now can i do this with SQL in SQL Server?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Where is your 'table' stored?  What programming language are you planning on using?

Comment: The table is stored in a Excel-Sheet.

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?

Comment: I did a INSERT Statement for each Match with Excel and i importet the sheet by MS SQL Import and nomalized it via sql. But is there a Best Practice or easier way?

Answer (score 0):

If this is xls data, you could run a straight-forward script to insert the same data into a SQL Server table. Then you could run a different `INSERT` query for each sport to get them into the format you require, and delete the original table.

Assuming first column in original table is called `Name`:

```
INSERT INTO [TableB] (Name, Sports)
SELECT Name, 'Soccer'
FROM [TableA]
WHERE Soccer=1

INSERT INTO [TableB] (Name, Sports)
SELECT Name, 'Football'
FROM [TableA]
WHERE Football=1

INSERT INTO [TableB] (Name, Sports)
SELECT Name, 'Basketball'
FROM [TableA]
WHERE Basketball=1
```